# How to locate the code used for encryption of qrcode message in apk file

Tags: encryption, apk

When I scan a QR code in this app it gives an encrypted message. I want to figure out what method this app used to encrypt their QR codes. I used Dextojar to look at the source code but couldn't figure out where or how the encryption was done.

Here is the source code:
https://apkpure.com/nl/ns/nl.ns.android.activity